# Export a Dialogflow agent and import into Alexa

Tags: dialogflow-es, alexa-skills-kit

I have a Dialogflow agent that I would like to import into the Alexa console and ultimately deployed on the Echo.  Referencing Dialogflow's documentation, it says

> You will get some files in the zip archive: **IntentSchema.json**, **SampleUtterances.baf** and number of .txt files according to used entities...

(I have no entities so I wouldn't expect any.)  However, my zip file did not contain the two files mentioned but rather an 'agent.json' file , a 'package.json' file and the intents folder with all my intents.

Looking at the contents and the number of intent files exported, the import of these into Alexa appears to be a lengthy process.  Is this correct?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you Exported the Dialogflow project by going to the Settings, selecting the "Export/Import" tab, and then exporting it. This does not create files that can be used for Alexa - this creates a project that you can re-import into Dialogflow.

To [export for Alexa](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/alexa-exporter):

1. Select "Integrations" on the left.
2. Scroll down and select the "Amazon Alexa" integration.

   [image]
3. Select the "Export for Alexa" button.

   [image]

Comment: That's exactly what I did. (My bad.) Thank you for pointing that out. So I got the two files: IntentSchema.json, SampleUtterances.txt now but it still seems that I have to enter each intent one by one; Interaction Model->Add Intent which only allows for one at a time.  In fact, you have all your intents in the 'IntentSchema' file and all the utterances for the intents are in the 'SampleUtterances' file so you have to create each intent separately (no import of the IntentSchema file) and then you can enter in bulk the utterances for that intent from the SampleUtterances file. Is this correct?

Comment: I think this is not a valid answer. The question still stands, because the json that we get from Dialogflow it can't be imported on Alexa. Or at least I haven't found one.

Comment: I'm unable to import in Alexa the exported files of Dialogflow

Answer (score 1):

**Amazon Alexa** importer and exporter are **no longer supported** in Dialogflow from the July 23, 2020

Here is release link https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/release-notes#July_23_2020